# Matomo (Piwik) tracks wrong URL in React App

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, matomo

I have a SPA build around React with `react-router` using browser history API to handle location changes. I also have Matomo (formerly Piwik) installed and configured.

I have written a middleware that listens for router's `@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE` action and calls Matomo tracker's `.trackPageVisit()` every time when such action is being fired.

Problem is, that Matomo somehow tracks only the first page's URL each time.

So, if I enter using `http://localhost` and then move to `http://localhost/page`, Matomo will track `http://localhost` twice instead of latter being `page`. When entering `/page` and moving to `/login` I will see in report `/page` being tracked twice. This lead me to a conclusion, that somehow Matomo does not handle browser's history manipulations through `history.pushState` in my configuration. I'm lookin for ideas what can be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that Matomo doesn't support the pushState on it's own.
You need to do it manually by using the `setCustomUrl` and then call `trackPageView()`.

More can be found here:
https://matomo.org/blog/2017/02/how-to-track-single-page-websites-using-piwik-analytics/